# Java Mysql query database with connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, connection

Thanks in advance for any help. I am creating a Database - Client application using java in Eclipse. I am using MySQL 5.6 for my database. I have a method to create and return a Connection Object that I will use for querying the database, and a method to return all of the rows in the table as a JSON array. The problem comes in the query method when trying to call the connection method.

at:  try{
            con.getDBConnection();
its telling me there is an error for getDBConnection(); and the suggestions that it gives is to add cast to 'con'.

and I can't get the query method to compile from the main method.

```
package binaparts.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import binaparts.util.ToJSON;

public class returnAllParts extends DBConnect{

    public JSONArray queryReturnAllParts() throws Exception{

        PreparedStatement query = null;
        Connection con = null;

        ToJSON converter = new ToJSON();
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

        try{
            con.getDBConnection();
            query = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * " + "from `parts list`" );

            ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();

            json = converter.toJSONArray(rs);
            query.close();
        }catch(SQLException SQLex){
                SQLex.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(con != null){
                con.close();
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

dao package code below:

```
package binaparts.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class DBConnect {

    private Statement st = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private Connection con = null;  
    private PreparedStatement pst = null;

    private String serverName = "localhost";
    private String portNumber = "3306";
    private String dbms = "mysql";
    private Object userName = "dwilson";
    private Object password = "abc";

    public Connection getDBConnection() throws SQLException {

        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

            try{
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" + this.serverName + ":" + this.portNumber + "/", connectionProps);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                con = null;
            }finally{
                if(con != null){
                     System.out.println("Connected to database");
                }
            }
        return con;
    }
    public String getUser(){
        try{
            DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
            String username = dmd.getUserName();
            //System.out.println("Current User: "+username);
            return username;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

main method below:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        DBConnect con = new DBConnect();
        try {
            con.getDBConnection();
            System.out.println(con.getUser());
            System.out.println(con.queryReturnAllParts());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Login loginGUI = new Login();
        //MainFrames m = new MainFrames();
        //m.displayGUI();
    }
}
```

The `System.out.println(con.getUser());` does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `returnAllParts#queryReturnAllParts` method, change

```
con.getDBConnection();
```

By

```
con = getDBConnection();
```

The problem is that `con` is a variable from `java.sql.Connection` and it doesn't have a `getDBConnection` method. Since your current `returnAllParts` class extends `DBConnect` class, it can access to the `public Connection getDBConnection` method with no problems.

> The System.out.println(con.getUser()); does work

This is because in your `Main#main` class, you have declared `DBConnect con`. Do not confuse this variable with the `con` variable declared in other methods.

---

Not directly related to the problem, but I suggest you some improvements to your current code/design:

- Change the name of your `returnAllParts` class for something more meaningful for future readers (even you in some days or weeks will become in a future reader of your code). From reading your code, it looks like this class should be renamed to `PartList`.
- Use a Database connection pool instead of manually get your connections. There are libraries that handle this for your like [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/)
- Probably you're new to programming, so it would be better that you start in the right way and develop your application in layers (further reading: [Multitier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)). With this basis, we can say that a DAO (or data service, depends how you name it) should only contain the methods to access and retrieve the data in a way other clients could consume it as they want/need, so it would be better returning a `List<PartList>` object and that another layer in your application (probably the closest to presentation) will apply the transformation from your objects to a JSON String.
- For a design point of view, it would be **way better** if your database access objects uses a `DBConnect` object instead of extending from it. In this way, you could have a single `DBConnect` object per database connection configuration associated to all the related DAOs.

Comment: going from con. to con = fixed the problem inside of the returnAllParts method - thanks. I was planning on using the returnAllParts class to hold the methods for querying the database, I was just testing the initial method. Would something along the lines of DatabaseQuery be more appropriate?

Comment: @Danny this really depends on what the class will do. If the `returnAllParts` is associated with any kind of query, then `DatabaseQuery` would be a proper name, if is just related with the `part list` table, then `PartListDAO` would be a better name.

Comment: +1 The improvement suggestions are more helpful in the long run than the question/answer themselves.

Comment: I am fairly new to writing actual java applications as opposed to bits of code to try things out, so improvement suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
    PreparedStatement query = null;
    Connection con ;

    ToJSON converter = new ToJSON();
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

    try{
        con.getDBConnection();
```

the variable `con` is of type `java.sql.Connection`, not `DBConnect`. That type does not have a `getDBConnection()` method. I believe you meant to use

```
 con = this.getDBConnection();
```

in your first `returnAllParts` class (which extends `DBConnect`). (Please use Java naming conventions.)

Comment: +1 and OP should also consider using a data source. I mean if someone has already made efforts to create DB helper classes, why not implement connection pooling as well?

Comment: @Ravi There are a few redundant things in his code. OP should start with setting up and using DataSource as you suggest.

Comment: I was trying to lookup how to implement the DataSource class but I couldn't quite figure it out, since I am not using a webservice tier to go through. I am planning on making a properties file that can be set from the application gui eventually.

Comment: @Danny You don't need to be in a webservice tier to create a `DataSource`. Check out the class [`BasicDataSource`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) from Apache commons-dbcp.

Comment: @Danny you can use BoneCP for that as well, note the updates on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your "returnAllParts" method you define `Connection con ;`.

That `Connection` is a java.sql.Connection object and it doesn't have the method you seek. Remove it.

Comment: I must have messed that up in formatting the post. It should have been Connection con = null; I have updated the source code